# Progressive Web Application Add to Homepage Update Problem on IOS

Tags: ios, reactjs, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I have created a web app using react. However, I am having hard time to update web app already added to homepage on ios. I see old contents every time, it does not cache the new javascript and display it immediately although, I can update it on android. Page life cycle of serviceworker on ios causes the problem or what. Anyone interested in? Thanks for help.

Comment: It should update new content while the user opens the app long enough for new content to load in the background. The next time the user opens the app, they should see the new content. This is the default behaviour.

Comment: because you are leaning on UI rendering you will also need to reload the page to access the new content once it is updated in the service worker.
You can facilitate this using messaging from the service worker to the UI via the messaging channel. This will allow you to display messages to the user to reload, etc.